# Jquery Slider issue in iPad which work fine in desktop and laptop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad

I have used one slider which work fine in laptop and desktop but when I open in iPad we lost that smoothness and come out with some jurk, I want same smooth effect as Desktop.

Please see the code in this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/uU8Mx/)

!! Quick response is appreciable !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `focus` instead of `click` that will work on iPad

Comment: that slider work in iPad even with click but smoothness in slide up and slide down does not look proper, so issue is not about "focus"

Comment: well then it is hard to understand because I have iPad but you can try  giving them value like 500 instead of slow. May be that will work

Comment: no that value even not worked if you open that link ,which I provided in my post, in your ipad you will get idea how slide come with jurk

Comment: Its work fine in iPad, I just changed jquery style with different way and now its work fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

wow,  I just changed different style and its work perfect now

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".hide").click(function(){
$(".pane").slideToggle(slow);
});
$("#togg a").click(function () {
    $("#togg a").toggle();
});     

})
```